# How to override priority in CSS classes?

Tags: html, css

- [Home](http://127.0.0.1/test/)
- [Option 1](http://127.0.0.1/test/option1/)
- [Option 2](http://127.0.0.1/test/option2/)

And I apply the styles with this classes

```
#contentheader .cat {
border-top:3px solid #ccc;
background-color:#eee;
overflow:hidden;
}

#contentheader .cat li a {
color:#999;
font-weight:700;
text-decoration:none;
font-size:13px;
display:block;
border-right:1px solid #fff;
float:left;
padding:10px;
}

#contentheader .cat li a:hover {
background-color:#E9E9E9;
}
```

The problem is that I need the first `<li>` (Home) to be different, maybe making the text in other color, or maybe making the font wider. I try assigning a class directly to the `<li>` or the `<a>` tags, but it doesn't works, it always take the styles in the `#contentheader .cat li a` class. What is the best way to do this? Thanks

Comment: The title should probably be changed because this isn't about overriding priority per-se. It's really just about selecting a single child element. Overriding priority is done with ! important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increase the [specificity of that selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) to have it override a rule with a lower selector specificity.

So if you assign the class to the `li` element, use `#contentheader .cat li`**`.class`** `a`, for the `a` element, use `#contentheader .cat li a`**`.class`**.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the :first-child selector in css:

```
#contentheader .cat ul li:first-child a {
    color: red;
}
```

That finds the first li child of the ul. Just make sure it comes after the general li case so that it takes precedence or use the ! important modifier on the color/size definitions.

Comment: Hardly a surprise, but IE6 doesn't support the first-child  pseudo selector. http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/ has a great overview of which browsers supports what.

Comment: Thanks, yes it can be a problem if it is not supported in all the actual most used web browsers.

Comment: IE 6 barely supports CSS though. :)

Comment: It is supported in IE 7 and IE 8 though.